# Simple factorization problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot find the solution! This is not a homework assignment.

> $11x^2+13x-7$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried for a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Since it's not a homework assignment, what is the context (e.g., where does it come from and why do you want to factor it) of the quadratic expression of $11x^2 + 13x - 7$ you're trying to factor?

Comment: Hello @Carlos , you should try the determinant : $\delta = b^{2}-4ac$ you have a,b,c ,and then you'll have 3 possibilities .

Comment: @JohnOmielan I think he wants the roots

Comment: You cannot factorise in the integers.

Comment: @JoshuaK The question title says "Simple *factorization* problem", with the emphasis being mine.

Comment: I was thinking to factorize with the roots :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about completing squares? Write your expression as $$11\left(x^2+\frac{13}{11}x\right)-7.$$ The goal is to write this as a difference of squares, which is easy to factorise. To this end, complete the square on the expression in brackets, which becomes $$x^2+2x\frac{13}{22}+\left(\frac{13}{22}\right)^2-\left(\frac{13}{22}\right)^2=\left(x+\frac{13}{22}\right)^2-\left(\frac{13}{22}\right)^2.$$

Thus our expression becomes $$11\left(x+\frac{13}{22}\right)^2-11\left(\frac{13}{22}\right)^2-7=\left(\sqrt {11}\left(x+\frac{13}{22}\right)\right)^2-\frac{169}{44}-7=\left(\sqrt {11}\left(x+\frac{13}{22}\right)\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{\frac{477}{44}}\right)^2,$$ from where you should now be able to continue.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! Many thanks!

Comment: @CarlosMascarua You're most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, do I have some good news for you. Allow me to introduce you to the math world's latest invention:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
The quadratic formula!

Basically, your equation is quadratic (the highest exponent on an $x$ is $2$), and it has the general form:
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
where $$a=11,b=13,c=-7$$
Plugging these values into the equation and evaluating gives two solutions:
$$x_{1}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\quad\text{AND}\quad x_{2}=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Now you can finish! Hope this helps!

P.S. You won't be able to factor this one, which is why I suggested using this to find the roots instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to apply the general factorization method, and lo! I realized I could find no formula of the form (dx+e)(fx+g). So is there a limitation that I should have considered to just give up on such attempt? (E.g. a, b and c being prime numbers?)

Comment: @CarlosMascarua Try to think of two integers $m,n$ so that $m+n=b$ and $mn=ac$. If you can't come up with values for $m$ and $n$, you should just use the formula. It works for any quadratic.